# Why can't I ask any Networking question on NE?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, asking-questions

I asked [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6630/775), but it was closed as off-topic.

I have a general question though; I think you should be able to ask any networking-related questions on Network Engineering - why not?

Answer (score 4):

Because "any networking-related question" is not what was decided is on-topic for this Stack Exchange site.

See the site's [birth information on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52519/network-engineering) for how it was created, and see [what can I ask here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for what the community ultimately decided was on-topic.